# Execute scheduled Task only once

Tags: c#, .net-core, schedule

I was trying to Code some simple scheduled Task, which should be executed every full minute (aka when seconds are at 0) but somehow it got messed up. Instead of only doing its job once, it does it over and over as long as the seconds are at 0.
I tried to prevent that by using a bool indicator, but that didnt work.

Hier is my Code example:

```
   static void Main()
    {
        bool now = true;

        while (true)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Second == 0 && now == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("now is: " + DateTime.Now);
                now = false;
            }
            else
            {
                now = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

I would prefer to not use sleeps or delays and would like to schedule it by actual time.
Is there an easy way to solve this?

Comment: Your title doesn't mesh with your question. The title says *once daily*, but the text says *every full minute*, which would be 1,440 times per day. Can you [edit] your post to make it more clear which one you're asking about doing?

Comment: You are looking for a product like celery or hangfire,

Comment: Edited it, thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not use a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer)?

Comment: Hm isn't there a way without using external packages? I mean it feels like that this should be super simple, i am probably just missing smth

Comment: @Herohtar i want it to be fixed to a specific time, thats why a timer which gets delayed over and over is not rly an option for me.

Comment: You could still use a timer to do that -- if your timer ticks once per second then you should only see `Second == 0` once every minute.

Comment: Just make the code do the job once, and do the reptition via the Task Sheduler. This seems way below the case where a dedicated programm for the repetition is nessesary.

Comment: Yes like i said i don't to use external packages, cause it should be possible without, as its simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of your current time and your next run time by changing your code to something like

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var nextRunTime = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, 0).AddMinutes(1);

    while (true)
    {
        var currentTime = DateTime.Now;

        if (currentTime >= nextRunTime)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currentTime);
            nextRunTime = nextRunTime.AddMinutes(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried your solution and it worked perfectly. I dont understand tho why it didnt work with setting a bool but works with setting a next runtime :(. do you know why thats the case?

Comment: Your while loop takes only a few milliseconds to execute and will, therefore, run several times a second. The first time your if conditions are met (second == 0 and now == true) you enter the first part of the if statement and you set now = false, but the while loop immediately runs again and now you do not meet the if conditions because second == 0 but now != true, so you enter the else part of the if statement and set now = true again. When the while loop execute for the third time within the second it will enter the first part of the if statement again because seconds == 0 and now == true

Comment: Oh yeah you right, thanks alot :). I guess i have overseen that.